# Is there an equivalent of Redis's "pipeline" in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, pipelining

In redis there is a way to "group" commands to reduce the number of exchanges between the client and the server. ([redis pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining))

When used with hundred or thousands of commands, it can dramatically reduce a server load.

Is there a equivalent in OrientDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [SQL BATCH](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html). Example:

```
begin
let account = create vertex Account set name = 'Luke'
let city = select from City where name = 'London'
let e = create edge Lives from $account to $city
commit retry 100
return $e
```